# Any Alternative to ImageIO.write to convert bufferedimage to GIF bytes (Faster than ImageIO)?

Tags: java, image, gif, javax.imageio, imaging

my problem is when using imageio.write i am seeing that is using hdd, also read about jDeli (but too expensive), Apache Commons, JAI that are much faster....

I wanna use the encoded bytes returned by routine... at a custom Remote Desktop Utility...

```
public static byte[] imageToJPEGByteArray(Image aImage, int width, int height, int qualityPercent) throws IOException {
 byte[] imageBytes = new byte[0];
 

   float quality = 75 / 100f;

   BufferedImage destImage;
   destImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(aImage, null);
 
   // Output JPEG byte array
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 
   if(qualityPercent != -1) {
       // Start to create JPEG with quality option
       ImageWriter writer = null;
       Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif");
       if (iter.hasNext()) {
         writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
       }
       ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
       writer.setOutput(ios); 
       ImageWriteParam iwparam = new JPEGImageWriteParam(Locale.getDefault());
       iwparam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
       iwparam.setCompressionQuality(quality);
       writer.write(null, new IIOImage(destImage, null, null), iwparam);
       ios.flush();
       writer.dispose();
       ios.close();
       // Done creating JPEG with quality option
   } else {
       // This one line below created a JPEG file without quality option
       ImageIO.write(destImage, "gif", baos);
   }
 
   baos.flush();
   imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
   baos.close();
 
   // Done
   return imageBytes; 
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing me: you say you're writing a GIF image, but the posted code uses JPEG. You say the problem with it is that it writes to the hard disk, but the code you posted appears to only write to in-memory objects.

Comment: yes it is a little confused... :-)
but thought using "gif" will be GIF 
ImageIO.write(destImage, "gif", baos);

but you have 100% right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that you've observed that this code appears to cause disk activity when saving to `ByteArrayOutputStream` perhaps you should try setting the `ImageIO` "use cache" flag to `false`:

```
ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
```

Javadoc for `setUseCache` says:

> Sets a flag indicating whether a disk-based cache file should be used when creating ImageInputStream and ImageOutputStreams.

Comment: wow! this improving a lot...